# cannot access feature modules without importing

Tags: angular, angular6, lazy-loading

We are building a MEAN web application with Angular6.
We have certain feature modules, let's say FormGeneratorModule and GridGeneratorModule.

What we want is that these should be imported only once in the root appModule and all the other child modules should have access to it directly, i.e., without having to import them in every child module that is going to use them.

I have done the research on it and implemented these feature modules accordingly (with exporting components that'll be used and everything). I have also imported BrowserModule in my root module and CommonModule in all the child modules (for lazy loading). But this still doesn't seem to work, I am still having to import these feature modules whenever I am using them in a different module. This is totally not desirable because these are pretty heavy modules.

For reference I am putting some code snippets here:

**root AppModule.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule as NgController, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { HomeComponent } from '@L3Modules/default/controllers/home/home.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@L3Modules/default/controllers/forms/forms.module';
import { FormGeneratorModule } from '@L3Modules/core/controllers/formGenerator/formGenerator.module';
import { GridGeneratorModule } from '@L3Modules/core/controllers/gridGenerator/gridGenerator.module';


const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
@NgController({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    FormGeneratorModule,
    GridGeneratorModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
```

**Feature modules:**

**formGenerator.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    routing,
    NgbModule,
],
declarations: [
    FormGeneratorComponent,
   ...
],
exports: [
    ...ALL the components
],
entryComponents: [
    BComponent,
    AComponent,
    DComponent,
    ...

],
providers: [DService],
schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```

**gridGenerator.module.ts**:

```
declarations : [
    ChComponent,
    PUComponent,
    DTComponent,
],
imports : [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    FormsModule
],
exports: [DTComponent],
providers: [],
entryComponents: [],
schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
```

It would be great if someone could help me out a bit here, I can't think of something that I am missing in order to avoid importing these giant feature modules in every module that uses them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's how angular module structure works and it doesn't make a difference if you import them in multiple modules of the same application because webpack will move it into a chunk for code reuse.

Comment: So what are you trying to say? So if the same module is imported in 5 different modules, it's same as importing it into one root app module? Is it something like require works in Node by caching the modules first time they are loaded?

Comment: The code is only added to your bundle once, even if you import the module 100 times. (There are some cases where code is added multiple times but not in your case)

Comment: okay then it is not a performance issue. I am still looking for a way to avoid having to import them in every module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply import your AppModule into each feature module:

**formGenerator.module.ts** or **gridGenerator.module.ts**

```
import { AppModule } from './../app.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule
    ...
  ]
```

Worth noting that there is no performance advantage to doing so